I am trying to write a sub procedure that will delete all table rows if the IT column value is equal to OO
I need the procedure to filter the table on the IT column where values equal OO, and from there just delete all of the sheet rows with that value. However, I am getting "run-time error '1004': delete method of Range class failed" when I try to write this sub procedure. Any suggestions would be appreciated!
This is what I have written, expecting it to do just that, however I am not sure what I am doing to trigger this error. I'm new to VBA so I'm struggling to troubleshoot right now.
Here is my current script, where CHECK_DETAIL is my table object that contains the IT column (field 18):
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("CHECK_DETAIL").Range.AutoFilter Field:=18, _
    Criteria1:="OO"
Range("CHECK_DETAIL").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete


The issue in your script is with how you're referencing the table and its rows for deletion. Specifically, you're using the Range("CHECK_DETAIL") syntax, which doesn't correctly reference the table object after filtering. Also, deleting rows in a filtered table requires careful handling to avoid runtime errors.
Sub DelTblRows()
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler ' Enable error handling
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range
    
    ' Attempt to set the table
    On Error Resume Next
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("CHECK_DETAIL")
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    If tbl Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Table 'CHECK_DETAIL' does not exist on the active sheet.", vbExclamation, "Table Not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Apply the filter
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="OO"
    
    ' Delete rows based on filter criteria
    With tbl.Range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        
        ' Check if any rows are visible
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            .AutoFilter
            rng.Delete
        Else
            MsgBox "No rows matching the criteria were found.", vbInformation, "No Rows Found"
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Clear the filter
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter
    
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    ' Handle errors and provide feedback to the user
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    On Error Resume Next
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter ' Clear filter if error occurred
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub


Thank you, this is great! I appreciate the notes as well. Like I said, I'm new to VBA, so the thorough response is much appreciated!

Unfortunately, my reputation is not high enough to upvote since my account is new. But I will as soon as I can. I'm sorry.
